# File not saved when submitting to ITunes

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

App developed with Appcelerator (SDK 7.5.0), tested on Simulators and Devices without problem.

When I create a package (without any error) for the Store and try to Validate/Distribute using XCode, I always receieve this generic error message :

**The file "embedded.mobileprovision" could not be saved in the folder [APP Name]**

I cannot find any information regarding this error, so I'm trying to understand if it is connected to the package created by Appcelerator or if it's something connected to Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to updated apple certificates.

I generated a new Distribution Certificate when the old one expired, so I had also to create a new provisioning profile for my app.

Unfortunately Xcode didn't update automatically the provisioning profiles.

To solve the problem:

1 close Xcode

2 delete all the files inside

/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

3 Reopen Xcode

4 Build APP and send it to ITunes...